# allow_disk_use not working on cursor in PyMongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient()
>>> db = client['cvedb']
>>> db.list_collection_names()
['cpeother', 'mgmt_blacklist', 'via4', 'capec', 'cves', 'mgmt_whitelist', 'ranking', 'cwe', 'info', 'cpe']
>>> colCVE = db["cves"]

>>> cve = colCVE.find().sort("Modified", -1) # this works

>>> cve_ = colCVE.find().allow_disk_use(True).sort("Modified", -1) # this doesn't work
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'allow_disk_use'
>>> cve_ = colCVE.find().sort("Modified", -1).allow_disk_use(True) # this doesn't work
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'allow_disk_use'
>>> cve.allow_disk_use(True) # this doesn't work
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'allow_disk_use'
>>>
```

I want to use `allow_disk_use()` method but getting the above-mentioned error. My MongoDB server is 4.4.1 and pymongo is also at the latest version.

I have referred to [Documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.allow_disk_use) and [Source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/d3e66a67021c3a587d125e46fb996c422164f2ba/pymongo/cursor.py#L440) but I am not able to get what am I doing wrong. Is not supposed to work with `Cursor` objects? it would be good if anyone could explain the correct approach and why this isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pymongo, you can use `allowDiskUse` in combination with `aggregate`:

```
cve_ = colCVE.aggregate([{"$sort": {"Modified": -1}}], allowDiskUse=True)
```

Since version 3.11 you can also pass it to `find()`:

```
cve_ = colCVE.find(allow_disk_use=True).sort("Modified", pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! is there any docs regarding that it works only on aggregate? how did you find it? according to this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.allowDiskUse/#cursor.allowDiskUse, it should work on cursor

Comment: I have to correct myself. See my edited answer. You have to pass it to the find-command instead of sort().

Comment: an argument inside sort doesn't seem to work, `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_disk_use'`

Comment: You have to pass 'allow_disk_use' to find, not sort, as suggested in my answer.

Comment: yes I passed to find and got the error mentioned in the above comment

Comment: which pymongo-version are you using?According to https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html the functionality was added in version 3.11. I use 3.11.0 and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

In addition to beachy's answer, after upgrading to the latest version(3.11),
the queries which were giving `AttributeError` (mentioned in the question) also happens to work perfectly.